# Specific GCC programs and libs for C compiling

Tags: c, gcc, mingw

I would like to know what are the specific programs (and libs) used by GCC in compiling a C program. I heard that when I call the executable program called "GCC", it doesn't really compile the program with itself. Instead, it will call another program for compiling and another program for linking. I also heard that we can convert C to an assembly language using -S option (so I think it's been translated by another program). I tried searching for the GCC documentation but I can't find the answer. What are the programs and libraries responsible for creating C programs? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use the `-v` option to see what `gcc` does, it stands for *verbose*.

Comment: Okay, thanks for that. But how can I know what does a program in the GCC does. Example, when I added a -S switch, what is the program responsible for translating the code?

Comment: Did you read the output? What was the last program called? And I'm curious, *why* do you want to know this? If you want to generate assembly code, just use `gcc -S` like everyone else, then you don't have to bother with the special flags needed by the actual compiler program.

Comment: Yes. I read the output. And I think the last program to called was GCC (well, I'm not sure about this). It was just the directory that the verbose switch was showing plus the version of GCC, GMP, and MPFR, and some sort of GCC flags (or parameters, I'm still not sure about this).

As for your second question, if we create an application and package it with the whole MinGW GCC, it will took a whole lot of time (and space). But if we use only a part of it (programs only used in debugging the application), maybe we can save more time (and space).

Comment: Then you didn't read it very well. On my system there's a line that says `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/cc1` followed by lots of arguments. This is the actual compiler that generating object files, *or* assembler files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GCC as such provides only the compilers: `cc` for C, `c++` for C++, and others. The other important programs are provided by the `binutils` package.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Binutils), they are:

- **as**   assembler popularly known as GAS (GNU Assembler)
- **ld**   linker
- **gprof**    profiler
- **addr2line**    convert address to file and line
- **ar**   create,   modify, and extract from archives
- **c++filt**  demangling filter for C++   symbols
- **dlltool**  creation of Windows dynamic-link libraries
- **gold**     alternative linker
- **nlmconv**  object file conversion to a NetWare   Loadable Module
- **nm**   list symbols in object files
- **objcopy**  copy object   files, possibly making changes
- **objdump**  dump information about object   files
- **ranlib**   generate indices for archives
- **readelf**  display content   of ELF files size     list total and section sizes
- **strings**  list   printable strings
- **strip**    remove symbols from an object file
- **windmc**       generates Windows message resources
- **windres**  compiler for Windows
  resource files